# Dumping Avahi & Bonjour, DNS-SD Zone Files

Tags: dns, go, multicast, mdns, avahi

I'm looking to make improvements to the Go library for mDNS: https://github.com/davecheney/mdns/

I've spoken with the author, who simply says "I got it to a point where it worked for me", and that's fine, well within the spirit of open source.

He mentioned some interoperability problems with Avahi, Bonjour and dns-sd discovery tools not finding the services he has exported.

I'm looking to understand what records are published by Avahi when doing a simple service with a port, and a simple name.

I had expected an appropriate version of:

```
dig @localhost .local -t AXFR
```

Might have Avahi export it's zone, but it didn't work for me (cue "you are doing it wrong"!) - I'd like to understand the minimum records exported by a typical Avahi service, and examine the same from the automatically exported `Lee-Hambleys-Macbook.local` from the Apple implementation on my notebook that I might be able to improve the Go lang support for mDNS.

When other people are working with Avahi/Bonjour/mDNS, what tools do they use to dig in and check that things are working as expected?

The kind folks of #avahi were kind enough to give me the following tip:

```
 killall -USR1 avahi-daemon
```

That causes `avahi-daemon` to dump it's zone file to the `syslog`.

But ideally I'd like to know how best to query the server, `tcpdump` also looks promising, but it's still only showing records that get lookedup, not a complete dump of everything that's in the zone:

```
sudo tcpdump dst port 53
Password:
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
09:43:28.883763 IP 192.168.178.41.50916 > resolver2.opendns.com.domain: 50479+ A? e3191.c.akamaiedge.net. (40)
09:43:29.046201 IP 192.168.178.41.61989 > resolver2.opendns.com.domain: 55378+ PTR? 251.0.0.224.in-addr.arpa. (42)
09:43:29.123784 IP 192.168.178.41.56659 > resolver2.opendns.com.domain: 26471+ A? p05-btmmdns.icloud.com.akadns.net. (51)
09:43:29.819277 IP 192.168.178.41.53504 > resolver2.opendns.com.domain: 32010+ PTR? 220.220.67.208.in-addr.arpa. (45)
09:43:47.379251 IP 192.168.178.41.50916 > resolver2.opendns.com.domain: 50479+ A? e3191.c.akamaiedge.net. (40)
09:43:55.900406 IP 192.168.178.41.60511 > resolver2.opendns.com.domain: 32846+ AAAA? lc22.prod.livefyre.com. (40)
09:44:04.115159 IP 192.168.178.41.50916 > resolver2.opendns.com.domain: 50479+ A? e3191.c.akamaiedge.net. (40)
^C
7 packets captured
3187 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: mDNS operates on port 5353 so you have to filter for that, not port 53. :-)

Comment: I don't think zone transfer are supposed to work with mDNS. I think you are confusing mDNS/DNS-SD with Avahi a bit, maybe? It might be worthwhile taking a couple hours to skim the RFCs: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762 and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6763

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost certianly mixing my terms up, as far as I know dns-sd expects DNS records to be exported to standard DNS, and mDNS operates on a different port, but the records look like DNS records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mDNS does simply not support zone transfers due the way the protocol works. As far as I can tell there are two possible approaches:

**1)** Try brute force approach, by querying the target (server/subnet). You can do this with dig, just send the query to multicast address and query for your target, eg.

> dig -x 192.168.0.10 -p 5353 @224.0.0.251

There are also a few ready scripts and tools that assist in enumerating mDNS targets. Some examples include

- [MDNSRecon](http://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2012/7/11/mdnsrecon.html)
- [avahi-browse](http://linux.die.net/man/1/avahi-browse)
- [mdns-scan](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/mdns-scan/)
- [Bonjour Dumper](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/bonjourdumper/id670221310?mt=12)
- [dns-sd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dns-sd.1.html) -Z and friends

**2)** Force the daemon to dump its zone file (or settings). You already found out that Avahi obeys

> killall -USR1 avahi-daemon

Apple's Bonjour includes [mDNSResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mDNSResponder.8.html) which does not implement dumping zone information. However you can add more logging for similar benefits

> A SIGUSR1 signal toggles additional logging, with Warning and Notice
>   enabled by default:
>
> ```
>    % sudo killall -USR1 mDNSResponder
> ```
>
> Once this logging is enabled, users can additionally use syslog(1) to
>   change the log filter for the  process. For example, to enable log
>   levels Emergency - Debug:
>
> ```
>    % sudo syslog -c mDNSResponder -d
> ```
>
> A SIGUSR2 signal toggles packet logging:
>
> ```
>    % sudo killall -USR2 mDNSResponder
> ```
>
> A SIGINFO signal will dump a snapshot summary of the internal state
>   to /var/log/system.log:
>
> ```
>    % sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder
> ```

Also, [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) might be used to debug protocol errors. This should be enough for solving interoperability errors.

Comment: I didn't try this out, but it all seems like solid advice, especially `dig`ing multicast address